# Create a table structure for related records that supports easy use in controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design, associations

I would like to build a task and tag tables. It is a many-to-many associations so a task can have many tags and a tag can be attached to many tasks.

I did it like this:

**Task**

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :note
      t.date :due_date
      t.boolean :finished, default: false
      t.references :tag, null: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Tag**

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :slug
      t.references :task, null: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**TaggedTask**

```
class CreateTaggedTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tagged_tasks do |t|
      t.references :task, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :tag, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

NOTE: I added the `null: true` since a task can have no tags and a tag can have no task associated

My question is:

What would be the proper way to implement this **in the controllers**?

My idea is that since a task can be tagged or not, when I create a task I check if it has been passed one or more tags and create a `tagged_task` per each tag. And if not just create a simple `task`.

But I wasn't sure it was the cleanest way of doing this. So any ideas are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I would argue the controller highly depends on how the UI should look like and should work. For example: Are the tags predefined? Or should users be able to define new tags on the fly? Should users select existing tags, by clicking on them, or will there be should a text field. Will users enter tags comma-separated? Or with checkboxes? Can tags contain whitespace?

Comment: If you want to create a many to many assocation then the `tasks.tag_id` and `tags.task_id` columns are completely superflouos. They can only hold one single value and the assocation will actually go through the join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the [Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) documentation your `models` would look like this for each table for a many-to-many association:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagged_tasks
  has_many :tags, through: :tagged_tasks
end

class TaggedTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagged_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :tagged_tasks
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I have it like that. I am more concerned about the controller logic in this case. I will update my question to make that clear. Thank you though!

Comment: Wouldn't you allow `tagged_tasks_attributes` in your `tasks_params` function and [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to allow this functionality?

Comment: While this answer was somewhat right you got the naming conventions wrong. `TaggedTask.model_name.plural == "tagged_tasks"`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your question, you're looking for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` feature set - that's the magic that you use in things like controller actions when creating related records at the same time as the "base" records. You can find more in this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#configuring-the-model although you'll want to click into the reference documentation too: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

You're also looking at a classic "many-to-many" association via a simple join table, and you can use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation in the models. More in the Rails Guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Cheers!